# Insert Into Changing first entry and not creating new entry

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010, insert-into

I am creating an access app to auto generate serial numbers for products. I am using the insert into command and it is just changing the first entry of the table rather than creating a new entry with the serial number that has been designated. When I go step by step I can see that all the entries have the desired values but when executed it only changes the first serial number.

```
    Function CreateRFBarrier(pfrm As Object, pValue As String) As Boolean

    Dim db               As Database
    Dim LInsert          As String
    Dim LSerialNumber    As String
    Dim LLoop            As Integer

   On Error GoTo Err_Execute

   Set db = CurrentDb()

   LLoop = 1

  'Create number of records based on BuildQuantity value
   While LLoop <= pfrm.BuildQuantity

     'Get next SerialNumber value (sequential number)
      LSerialNumber = NewItemCode("OD")

      If LSerialNumber = "" Then
       GoTo Err_Execute
      End If

     'Create new record
      LInsert = "Insert into RFBarrier "
      LInsert = LInsert & " VALUES ("
      LInsert = LInsert & "'" & LSerialNumber & "'"
      LInsert = LInsert & ", " & pfrm.WorkOrder
      LInsert = LInsert & ", " & pfrm.BuildQuantity
      LInsert = LInsert & ", " & pfrm.DateCreated & ""
      LInsert = LInsert & ", " & pfrm.CreatedBy & ")"

     db.Execute LInsert, dbFailOnError

     LLoop = LLoop + 1

   Wend

   Set db = Nothing

   CreateRFBarrier = True

   Exit Function

Err_Execute:
   'An error occurred
    CreateRFBarrier = False
    MsgBox "An error occurred while trying to add new RFBarrier serial numbers."

End Function
```

Comment: How is `NewItemCode("OD")` implemented? Also, if it's a "sequential number", why isn't it an auto-number field in the table? You shouldn't even need to manage your primary key assignments.